# The TPM file could not be parsed (MiKTeX)

Tags: errors, pdftex, miktex, texniccenter

Today i wanted to continue working on my paper on a different machine.

I installed MiKTex and TexnicCenter the same way i did on my first machine.

After loading the project i tried to compile it.

I get this error:

```
pdflatex> initexmf.exe: The TPM file could not be parsed
pdflatex> initexmf.exe: Data: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tpm\packages\bidi.tpm
pdflatex> initexmf.exe: The operation failed for some reason.
pdflatex> initexmf.exe: Data: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\bin\initexmf.exe
```

I need to finish up the paper today so i really appreciate your help!

Edit: I just reinstalled MiKTeX and now it works again.

Comment: Try if works if you change the repository. And don't panic: It is possible to install packages manually - that's only a bit more work than with the package manager.

Comment: i went ahead and uninstalled miktex (which threw the same error). after reinstalling it did work again. thank you for your tip. next time i won't panic and try that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is could be solve with a software reinstallation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled MiKTeX which threw the same error again but apparently was still successful.

After reinstalling MiKTeX everything worked as expected again.

This solution is not ideal but it did the job.